# Rails - delete migrations vs remove tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been building an app for the last 5 months and I'm about to release the Alpha. It's been through many changes in that time and as a result has a lot of leftover tables and columns in the database that aren't being used anymore.

My question is, as there is no data in the app, would it be ok for me to just delete the actual migrations and then reset the database instead of creating new migrations to remove tables and columns? Or would there be a downside to that that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the guides on [migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)

> Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source
>   for your database schema. That role falls to either db/schema.rb or an
>   SQL file which Active Record generates by examining the database. They
>   are not designed to be edited, they just represent the current state
>   of the database.
>
> There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of
>   an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler
>   and faster to just load into the database a description of the current
>   schema.

It seems you're slightly misunderstanding the roles of migrations, they are not meant to be run again to set up your db, that role is for `schema.rb` to fill with the command

```
rake db:schema:load
```

I would suggest to remove all the migrations and then remove the tables and columns you don't want from the db and then you can run

```
rake db:migrate
```

which will generate an updated `schema.rb` file for you with the version of the db you want.

Comment: I think you're right Iceman, I seem to have a fundamentally flawed understanding of migrations. I'll do some reading on migrations and then apply your solution once I understand it better. Thanks for answering, much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The advantages of these migrations are: Coding with more than one person -> easy setup development env and sharing db.

And you can push your App to any environment and you dont have to take care about the state of your database. The migrations will tell you !

In your case it's a bit weird: You worked alone on a project for 5 month and you have never thought of cleaning up unused tables or columns !!?? What I suggest you: Write down (on paper) what tables and columns you really need and then you have two option:

1. Write migration which removes unneded columns and tables OR
2. if you dont have live data and you dont take care of a reset AND you want to spend extra time, you could create a fresh set of migrations with your tables and columns from your (paper)-sheet

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks for the response. Sorry I wasn't clear but I actually wasn't working alone, it has been me and one other dev. We each have our development environment plus a staging site on Heroku and a live site on Heroku. We haven't removed tables up until now because we haven't been sure of the business direction until now. With regards to your suggestions, why is one option not to simply delete only the migrations that are now irrelevant and then resetting the database? Is that not a viable option? Thanks